# Memory Leak in Rails App... string nightmare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, memory, heroku, memory-leaks

So I've got this rails app with a horrible memory leak problem. I'm running it on Heroku, and for the last couple days while I've been trying to figure out what on earth is causing it, I've had to continually restart the app every 5 hours or so or the memory exceeds 512 and my app crashes.

I'm using Oink, and I'm not seeing anything fishy with my instantiated classes. The only thing is that with each page load, the memory used creeps up. It doesn't even matter which page I load, it's seemingly random.

New Relic hasn't been much help either, since it doesn't have to do with any one particular controller action.

The only thing I've been able to find was using ObjectSpace, which revealed an ENORMOUS number of string objects in memory, and the number just grows and grows. I used a little tool to log the value of the strings and they're all blank. Not nil... but whitespace. My production app regularly has over 200,000 string objects in use.

Does anyone have any idea what these could possibly be coming from? This is really stressing me out having to be at my computer every five hours to keep my site alive.

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to give specific advice other than just removing code until you have the smallest possible example that exhibits the problem & post that

Comment: And run it up on an alternative server, and hit it with constant CURL requests until you can repro.

Comment: advice: dont do `string = string1 + string 2`, nor `string += string1`. Do: `string << string 1`, no additional string is created this way

Comment: Okay, major breakthrough. It seems I'm only leaking memory on pages that use the HAML engine. If I render erb, no leak. If I turn my layout off and render nothing on the same controller actions that were leaking before, no leak. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Okay maybe not. I'm realizing now that this might have something to do with the garbage collector. I noticed that I have random partials that are taking WAY longer than other identical ones to render. When I Googled it, I found this post: http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/rails3-unbearably-slow-view-rendering-use-ree-with-gc-tuning/

It's weird though, because I didn't upgrade from Rails 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, this is absolutely ridiculous, but after two weeks of anxiety and struggle, I found the solution to this leak. It literally all came down to this one line:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

in my application.rb config file.

It should have been:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I have no idea how I got it wrong, but boy did it wreak havoc on my app.

Does anyone know why this would cause such a problem? I was losing about a megabyte of memory on every single query. Crazy.

Comment: Thanks for this, you probably just saved me some serious headache.

Comment: How did you figure this out? My Rails app is making Strings like crazy and I have no idea how to trace what is creating them.

Comment: @MihaRekar it was terrible. I literally had to go back in time through months of commits, loading and booting each one, and then hammering the server with requests using the Apache benchmark tool until I found the revision that didn't have any problems. Then I piece-by-piece removed each change until I found the one that made the leak stop. It took days.